# XSLT to remove timestamps from all elements except one

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XSLT to remove timestamps & convert attributes into elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="namespace" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@*]">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="text() and @*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*[contains(name(), 'Date') and not(ancestor-or-self::EventDate)]">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,10)"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

& my source XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone='yes'?>
<CaseEvent xmlns="namespace">
<TransactionInfo>
<EventDate>2016-06-02T02:07:30.000-04:00</EventDate>
<CaseID>872519</CaseID>
</TransactionInfo>
<NewCaseEvent>
<Case changeType="I">           
    <Plan changeType="I">
    <Provision>
          <ProvisionTextValue>70</ProvisionTextValue>
          <EffectiveDate>2016-01-01-05:00</EffectiveDate>
        </Provision>
    </Plan>    
    <BillGroup changeType="I">
      <BillGroupIdentifierDate>2016-01-01-05:00</BillGroupIdentifierDate>
      </BillGroup>     
  </Case>
  </NewCaseEvent>
 </CaseEvent>
```

I want to remove timestamp from all Date Elements except **EventDate**

Expected Output:

```
    <CaseEvent  xmlns="namespace">
<TransactionInfo>
    <EventDate>2016-06-02T02:07:30.000-04:00</EventDate>
    <CaseID>872519</CaseID>
</TransactionInfo>
<NewCaseEvent>
    <Case changeType="I">
        <Plan changeType="I">
            <Provision>
                <ProvisionTextValue>70</ProvisionTextValue>
                <EffectiveDate>2016-01-01</EffectiveDate>
            </Provision>
        </Plan>
        <BillGroup changeType="I">
            <BillGroupIdentifierDate>2016-01-01</BillGroupIdentifierDate>
        </BillGroup>
    </Case>
</NewCaseEvent>
</CaseEvent>
```

If I remove namespace from source XML, this XSL is working fine, but if namespace is added then it is not generating the expected result.
Appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the namespace in your xsl without a prefix, use `xmlns:my="namespace"` and then prefix all your references of your element names with `my:`  - though I don't see any, but you must also change **all** your `name()`s in you xpaths to `local-name()`

## Edit

To keep the timestamp at the EventDate, replace

```
and not(ancestor-or-self::(my:)EventDate)
```

by

```
and local-name() != 'EventDate'
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks for your reply, However I am not using prefix in my xml. I tried changing namespace declaration & **name()** in the XSLT as per your suggestion but I don't see any change to the output.